# Are all of the edge descriptors necessary to differentiate edges?

Tags: computer-vision, edge-detection, image-processing

My question is about edge descriptors produced from an edge detection method applied on an *object image*. As we know, an edge has four descriptors **edge normal**, **edge direction**, **edge position**, and **edge strength**.  These descriptors are used for differentiating between the detected edges.

Are all of this descriptors are necessary? When can I dismiss any of these descriptors?

I am thinking about assumptions based on the properties of the input image, e.g., if the input image has no noise, can I neglect the **edge strength** and assume that all resulting edge points are true edges?

Comment: What are you using the descriptors for? What kind of input images do you have? Necessary for what? Without more info, it's hard to impossible to answer meaningfully

Comment: @penelope i have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the edge direction from the edge normal by atan2(y,x)[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).
The other descriptors are independent of each other and thus only the problem itself can tell if they are necessary or not.